# How to set environment variable in docker desktop in windows?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I used command "docker pull mysql:5.7.28" which showed image and container correctly in docker desktop but when trying to run the container it showed exited and error was MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD required.

So I need to edit MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD in yaml file to resolve this issue.
Now the problem is simple I have not used docker-compose file to setup the container and unable to find option in docker desktop to set up this variable.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You _create_ a docker-compose.yml file to set up your containers.

Comment: I used command "docker pull mysql:5.7.28" which showed image and container correctly in docker desktop but when trying to run the container it showed exited and error was MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD required.

Comment: FYI, I posted a quite similar Question on sister site, SuperUser Stack Exchange. See: [*How to add an environment variable to a container in Docker Desktop?*](https://superuser.com/q/1803976/212610)

Comment: OP asked about "Docker Desktop", which is a different way to run Docker. I would love to have the answer to this question, so maybe somebody who knows what Docker Desktop is would respond.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can set the environment variable when you run the container with `docker run` - see, e.g. "Start a `mysql` server instance" on https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql.

An alternative would be to create a `docker-compose.yml` and set the environment variable there (the reference for what you can put in Compose files is [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)).

There might be a way to set environment variables in Docker Desktop, but I don't use it, so I don't know. The documentation should tell you, though.

Comment: Why did this question get accepted? It doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: This provides every answer except the one looked for.